# Saving and retrieving checkbox value from local storage in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, ionic-framework, local-storage, ion-toggle

I have some problem, in my Ionic app use toggle to switch on/off function. By default toggle is true, when toggle change it switch to false.

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="myToggle.checked" ng-change="myToggleChange()">
  Toggle
</ion-toggle>
```

All work fine when use app, but if I close app and switch is false before closing when I load app again toggle has true by default when my controller start. How cache toggle after reload app has position before closing?
Controller:

```
      $scope.myToggleChange = function() {

        if($scope.myToggle.checked == true){
            console.log('Is True', $scope.myToggle.checked);
        }
        if($scope.myToggle.checked == false){
            console.log('Is False', $scope.myToggle.checked);
        }
      };

      $scope.myToggle = { checked: true };
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved by 10 hours reading docs and manuals )))

```
  $scope.myToggleItem = localStorage.getItem('check');

    if($scope.myToggleItem){    
      var item = localStorage.getItem('check');  
      $scope.myToggle = {checked: JSON.parse(item)};

    } else {    
      $scope.myToggle = { checked: true };
    }

  $scope.myToggleChange = function() {

    if($scope.myToggle.checked == true){
        console.log('Item', $scope.myToggle.checked);
        localStorage.setItem('check', $scope.myToggle.checked);
    }
    if($scope.myToggle.checked == false){
        console.log('Item', $scope.myToggle.checked);
        localStorage.setItem('check', $scope.myToggle.checked);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the localstorage to store such data.
https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

in your change handler you can store the value using

```
 $localStorage.myToogleValue = $scope.myToggle
```

you controller can check at the beginning

```
if ($localStorage.myToogleValue)
    $scope.myToggle = { checked: $localStorage.myToogleValue.checked };
else
    $scope.myToggle = { checked: true };
```